# Вызываю из статического блока метод, не инициализирует

Tags: java, классы, static, инициализация

Из статического блока вызываю метод который инициализирует массив (причем в самом методе это видно - выводит 35). Но когда обращаюсь в коде - оказывается что он не инициализирован (выводит null), это как?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + Environment.array[0]);
    }
}

class Environment {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static initialization");
        method();
    }
    static Integer[] array = new Integer[100];
    static void method() {
        System.out.println("Method");
        array = new Integer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            array[i] = 35;
        System.out.println("Value (static init): " + Environment.array[0]);
    }
}
```

Результат:

> Static initialization
>
> Method
>
> Value (static init): 35
>
> Value: null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хоть @Igor и технически верно ответил на вопрос, но немного деталей подкину. Статические поля в Java инициализируются в том порядке, в котором они определены.

[jls-12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4):

> The static initializers and class variable initializers are **executed
>   in textual order**

Если вы переместите объявление массива перед `static` блоком с вызовом `method`, то всё будет ок.

```
class Environment {
    static Integer[] array = new Integer[100];

    static {
        System.out.println("Static initialization");
        method();
    }
    static void method() {
        System.out.println("Method");
        array = new Integer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            array[i] = 35;
        System.out.println("Value (static init): " + Environment.array[0]);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> Static initialization
>   Method
>   Value (static init): 35
>   Value: 35

Answer (score 2):

тут более человекочитаемое объяснение, без "магии":
инициализация `static Integer[] array = new Integer[100];` заменяет собой уже заполненный массив
ты использовал `Integer` - он передается по ссылке, значение по-умолчанию `null`
новый массив не заполнялся значениями - он длиной 100 и заполнен `null`